# Azure Storage Queues, no data on queue but messages in queue

Tags: azure-storage-queues

I don't understand why I have this:

[image]

It says: "No data available in table"
but down there says: "Showing 0 of 7 messages in queue"

Why are 7 messages in queue and can't see them?

If I inspect another queue, the behavior is different:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot 2 depicts the situation when the queue is empty i.e. it does not contain any messages.

Screenshot 1 depicts the situation when the queue contains messages (7 in your case) but all the messages have been dequeued. When a message is dequeued, it becomes invisible for certain time (known as message visibility timeout) to other callers (Storage Explorer in your case).